# how to call jQuery code within div

Tags: jquery

I came across this jQuery plugin for vertically centering a div:

```
(function ($) {
    // VERTICALLY ALIGN FUNCTION
    $.fn.vAlign = function() {
        return this.each(function(i){
            var ah = $(this).height();
            var ph = $(this).parent().height();
            var mh = Math.ceil((ph-ah) / 2);
            $(this).css('margin-top', mh);
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

The author writes:

"Then you can use `$(‘.classname’).vAlign();` or `$(‘#image’).vAlign();` – Make sure to use this once the document has loaded, within `$(document).ready(function(){}`)!"

I understand pasting that within `$(document).ready(function(){})`, but how do I call it to my div (actually an image), if, for example, I have the div as `id="statement"`?

Plugin came from : 
http://atomiku.com/2012/02/simple-jquery-plugin-for-vertically-centering/

Comment: `$(‘#statement’).vAlign()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JQuery allows you to select elements using many different selectors

See the following for a good list: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Most things can be selected like CSS, try the following to select your DIV

```
 $("#statement")
```

Comment: I understand that ,but where to I put that selector? Within the plugin code?

Comment: No need to place it within their plugin.

After the plugin is loaded, you can use it with the rest of your javascript. Small things like that you would want to do once you can place in a script tag at the bottom of the page.

<script>
var myDiv = $('#statement);
//Do whatever with myDiv, like call vAlign.
</script>

Answer (score 0):

As the author say you need to call it with this after the plugin function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#statement').vAlign();
})
```

**Edit**

After make a [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GRmjU/1/) with this plugin I notice an issue with the manage of `margin-top` value. So if you have a problem at some point with that you can change it for `top` **[Like This](http://jsfiddle.net/GRmjU/)**.